# Django/python: (1048, "Column 'date' cannot be null")

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have created a Django project in which type-1 users can create a Post and type-2 users can bid on a post out of post_queryset = Post.objects.filter(accepted=False). Finally, post_owner can accept a bid.  After accepting I wanted to remove the accepted_object from post_queryset. So, I created a view(accept_bid) in which a type-1 user can accept a bid and simultaneously it passes a BooleanField(accepted) = True. With this, the post will no longer appear in the post_list page. But when I saving the accept_bid instance, it raising an IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'date' cannot be null"). I'm not sure whether my approach in changing the BooleanField() = True in my view is correct. I would appreciate helping me solve this.

Here's My code:

Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    item = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    post_owner = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    date = models.DateField()
    accepted = models.BooleanField(default = False)


class Bid(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name = bids)
    amount = models.IntegerField(max_length = 20)
    bidder = models.ForeingKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class Auction(models.Model):

    post = models.OneToOneField(Post)
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    bid = models.OneToOneField('truck.Bid', related_name='auctions')
```

forms.py:

```
class AcceptedForm(forms.ModelForm):
accepted = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('accepted', )
```

views.py:

```
def accept_bid(request, post_id, bid_id):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)
    bid = get_object_or_404(Bid, id=bid_id)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = AuctionForm(request.POST or None)
        form1 = AcceptedForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():
            accept_bid = form.save(commit=False)
            accept_bid.bid = bid
            accept_bid.post = post
            accept_bid.post_owner = request.user
            accepted = form1.save()
            accepted.accepted = True
            accept_bid.save()

            form.save()
            form1.save()
    else:
        form = AuctionForm()
        form1 = AcceptedForm()

    context = {

            "bid_id" : bid_id,
            "post_id" : post_id,
            "bid": bid,
            "post":post,
            'form': form
            'form1': form1,

         }
     return render(request, 'loggedin_load/active_deals.html', context)
```

TraceBack:

```
Traceback:

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py" in execute
  112.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in execute
  226.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.         raise errorvalue

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in execute
  217.             res = self._query(query)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in _query
  378.         rowcount = self._do_query(q)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in _do_query
  341.         db.query(q)

 File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py" in query
   280.             _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

 During handling of the above exception ((1048, "Column 'date' cannot be null")), another exception occurred:

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in  get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\sumanth\Desktop\django-custom-user-master\search field\Project\mysite\personal\views.py" in accept_bid
  447.          accepted = form1.save()

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save
  451.             self.instance.save()

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  708.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  736.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  820.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  859.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1039.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1060.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py" in execute
 117.                 six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py" in execute
  112.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in execute
  226.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.         raise errorvalue

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in execute
  217.             res = self._query(query)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in _query
  378.         rowcount = self._do_query(q)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py" in _do_query
  341.         db.query(q)

File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py" in query
  280.             _mysql.connection.query(self, query)

Exception Type: IntegrityError at /post/3/bid/7/
Exception Value: (1048, "Column 'date' cannot be null")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error trips when you try to save `form1` rather than when saving the `accept_bid` instance:

```
File "C:\Users\sumanth\Desktop\django-custom-user-master\search field\Project\mysite\personal\views.py" in accept_bid
  447.          accepted = form1.save()
```

`form1` is a ModelForm based on your `Post` model. Since your `Post` model already has an `accepted` attribute, you don't have to manually define a field for it like you did here - including that field in the `Meta` definition for the form like you've done is enough.

You will need to do one of three things from there:

1. Also include the `date` field in your ModelForm so that it can be set by the submitter,
2. Set up your model to either automatically include a date on creation (`auto_now_add=True`), or to allow that field to be blank. Or,
3. Use `commit=False` to interrupt the save and add a date to your object:

   ```
   accepted = form1.save(commit=False)
   accepted.date = ...
   accepted.save()
   ```

Also note that here:

```
accepted = form1.save()
accepted.accepted = True
```

You save `accepted` to your database, then update the object locally. The second line is only updating the object in memory, not the database. If you `print accepted.accepted` it will indeed show up as `True`, but if you re-fetch the object from the database and then try it again it'll show up as `False` since that change was never saved to the DB.

Comment: Actually the date field is to be set for the delivery purpose. So I can't make it to auto_now_add. How can i get the existed date value from Post object and set it in my views. I did accepted.date = post.date. But its not working. Thanks.

Comment: When you say it isn't working, what do you mean exactly? Is `post.date` not equal to the value you expect? Or are you getting a new error message? Or the same error again?

Comment: Make sure you are doing `accepted = form1.save(commit=False)` first, then set `accepted.date = post.date`, and lastly `accepted.save()`. It sounds like you are doing a `save()` without `commit=False` before setting that date attribute. If I'm wrong about that, could you post the form handling in your updated view?

Comment: @souldex, I again facing a new problem. the value of the accepted is not going to the existed post object. In my database, it creates a new object with existed date field and other fields as null. Can you once again help me in how to update the existed object! May be I'm missing with passing the post_id to the updated view.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow; right now `form1` is set up to create a new Post object. Are you wanting it to edit an existing Post object? If so, you will want to pass the object you want to edit to the form when it is instantiated and being processed using the `instance` keyword (`form1 = AcceptedForm(instance=...)` and `form1 = AcceptedForm(request.POST, instance=...)` respectively). If I am misunderstanding, feel free to PM me through my website at souldeux.com since our comment conversation is getting kind of long here.

Comment: I have posted the details about my new error through your website. Awaiting for your response.